# Getting the last index of a certain string element java?

Tags: java, arrays

There is an index of method already written, but how would I use this to find the last instance of a certain string in an array?

```
public int indexOf(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        if (string.equals(strings[index])) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```

Comment: `string.equals(strings[index])` where is `strings` coming from?

Comment: thats the string array :)

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the loop and start at the end of the array.

```
public int indexOf(String string) {
   if (string == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
   }
   for (int index = size-1; index >= 0; index--) {
      if (string.equals(strings[index])) {
          return index;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java strings also have a [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) method which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.lastIndexOf
```

and

```
String.lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the index and the returning it:

```
int lastIndex = -1;
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    if (string.equals(strings[index])) {
        lastIndex = index;
    }
}
return lastIndex;
```

The reply from Cattwood should be more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `lastIndexOf` method and iterate the array backwards. That is, something like -

```
public int lastIndexOf(String string) { 
  if (string == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
  for (int index = strings.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    if (string.equals(strings[index])) {
        return index;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the method nor create a new one you have to reverse the array and operate on the reversed:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(strings);
int reverseIndex = indexOf("myString");
int realIndex = reverseIndex > 0 ? strings.length - (reverseIndex + 1) : -1;
ArrayUtils.reverse(strings); //Back to normal
```

Answer (score -1):

what about simple answer

getthe size of the array legth.

```
ArrayList arry = new ArrayList()<String>;
if(arry!=null) {
int last = arry.legth() -1  ;
//no loop proudly
arr[last];  
return last ;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not what OP is asking. He wants the last _occurence_ of a specific string.